# Filtering an Object in Array with javascript in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, filter

I'm stuck on something I think it is just stupid but after trying some stuffs, I can't find the solution. Any advice ?

I have an array with objects in this format :

```
   [
    Object {
      "name": "name",
     "description": "100 jours ferme",
     "image: "path_image",
     "culture": Array [
      Object {
        "name": "name",
        "value": "309",
      }
    ]}
    ...
    ]
```

With a function in my `react native` project I get a `selected value`, for instance : `309`

So what i'm trying to do is to create a `New Array` with only the items containing this value in my Object inside `culture` and modifying the state of my array (with setState)

I know I can map all the `culture` array with `.map()` but then I'm stuck.
I just want to say "I want a new array with these elements" ...

Then, I know if I had something like that :

```
"culture": 309
```

I could have done that : `myArray.filter(i => i.culture == selectedValue)`

Any help on how I can do that with `.filter(), .map()` ?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) over the array, then for each `culture` run [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) with the predicate of

```
o => o.value === selectedValue
```

Here is a running example:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: "name",
    description: "100 jours ferme",
    image: "path_image",
    culture: [{
      name: "name",
      value: "309"
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "name",
    description: "100 jours ferme",
    image: "path_image",
    culture: [{
      name: "name",
      value: "308"
    }]
 }
];

const selectedValue = '309';
const newArr = arr.filter(obj => obj.culture.find(o => o.value === selectedValue));
console.log(newArr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: I have an error trying that :
`undefined is not an object (evaluating 'obj.culture.find')`... any idea ?

Comment: Seems like you got undefined instead of an object. I can't really know without a [mcve]

Comment: your example is working right. and if I copy in a static way the data I receive through an `API`, it's working too ... but I just try to filter/find what I get with the `API` and I have in my state. It is not.
For info, I'm passing my data through the params of `React Navigation` (the static data works, the one from the API no.)
Then to let you know that I receive an object in this format : {{info},{info}} and I transform it like this : Object.values(response.data)
Maybe there are some clues :-)

Comment: You should include in your question the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

To filter array with specific key,

```
var filterArray = detailArray.filter(
      data => data.service === serviceIdentifier,
    );
```